# new SimpleDateFormat("Pattern") vs applyPattern("Pattern") difference and performance benefit if any?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I was working on code in Java 7 which used extensive date conversions to String and From string to Date object, for which they were creating new SimpleDateFormat("Pattern") whenever they needed the date to be converted(5-6 patterns were there overall). So I need to ask that what if I write some code like this:

```
private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();

private SimpleDateFormat getsiSimpleDateFormat(SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat, String format){
    simpleDateFormat.applyPattern(format);
    return simpleDateFormat;
}
```

So here I am reusing my simpleDateFormat and just adding a pattern where ever necessary.

- Is this approach good?
- Or there can be some more improvement?
- By using this approach would I face increase in processing or memory?

Comment: Why don't you just profile the code yourself to measure differences in performance? Note also that reusing `SimpleDateFormat` objects is a little bit risky as they are not thread-safe. You'd have to make sure that all usages of a `SimpleDateFormat` object are synchronized.

Comment: Do not worry about performance unless you know for a fact that you are having a performance issue. If in doubt, conduct tests to find out whether you have.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yeah threading issues might be a problem. Thanks if I implement this then I will try to make it synchronized.

Comment: @Anant666 Which might actually slow things down instead of making them faster.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have some 6 `SimpleDateFormat` instances and you consider reducing, maybe to just 1? I can’t see that that will ever gain you a performance difference that anyone will be able to measure.

Comment: @OleV.V. The performance point is just out of curiosity as sometimes if we make some changes we should know their overall impact.

Comment: FYI: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is part of the old troublesome date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java that are no longer used. Now legacy, they are supplanted entirely by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two are sensibly the same. Looking into the code, you can see that using the basic constructor leads to :

```
public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)
{ 
    this(pattern, Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
}
```

The `this` leads to:

```
public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)
{
    if (pattern == null || locale == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    initializeCalendar(locale);
    this.pattern = pattern; // This part is important
    this.formatData = DateFormatSymbols.getInstanceRef(locale);
    this.locale = locale;
    initialize(locale);
}
```

Using `applyPattern(pattern)` on the other hand gives this result:

```
public void applyPattern(String pattern)
{
    compiledPattern = compile(pattern);
    this.pattern = pattern; // Same as initialization
}
```

As pointed out by [Roby Cornelissen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen) in the comments, both approaches are not exactly the same. `applyPattern` supposes you have already initialized your `SimpleDateFormat`, but skips the locale + calendar initialization. 
In both performance and memory, using `applyPattern` is better that re-creating an object. The former answer was:

> There are, subsequently, only one difference: using `applyPattern` will use less memory, as you are using only one object instead of re-initializing a `new SimpleDateFormat()`. The choice is up to you.

And is not completely correct (there are more than one difference).

---

**EDIT**

If any of you wonder, the `initialize()` method from the constructor compiles the pattern, thus throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` if you give it a wrong pattern either. The code (I posted here in the first place) makes it look like it would not crash.

Comment: I don't understand the logic about them being the same. Using `applyPattern()` skips both `initializeCalendar(locale)` and `initialize(locale)`. Yes, obviously both assign the `pattern` at some point, but I don't think variable assignment is where a possible performance bottleneck will lie.

Comment: I went from the principle that OP wanted to know the differences considering the pattern. But it is true that this is also something to point out. I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is part of the old troublesome date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java that are no longer used. Now legacy, they are supplanted entirely by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Use `DateTimeFormatter` instead.

## Thread Safety

The legacy date-time classes are *not* [thread-safe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). If your app uses threads, or might possibly in the future, then you should not pass around an instance of `SimpleDateFormat` to be reused.

In contrast, the java.time classes use immutable objects and are thread-safe. You may indeed retain a `DateTimeFormatter` to be passed around and reused.

## Premature Optimization

You seem to be falling into the trap known as [premature optimization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization). Programmers are notoriously inept at predicting the performance of their apps. Expected bottlenecks often run smoothly while other ignored code chokes. Modern hardware and operating systems make performance even trickier to predict.

Today’s JVM implementations are highly tuned, likely the most highly tuned software in history. Trust them to run your code well.

Other than a few basics such as avoiding unnecessary instantiations and network connections within large loops that run often, do not worry about  performance. Instead use [profiling tools](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)), [monitoring tools](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions), and some [logging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J), to determine and **measure the actual performance** of your app to identify legitimate performance concerns.

Comment: Yeah Basil I can use DateTimeFormatter from Java 8 and it is a better choice too. But here I am using Java 7 so I have to stick to the old classes available. I forgot to mention that in my question. Thanks for explaining the DateTimeFormatter I will use it in my future work.

Comment: @Anant666 Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Well worth the bother of adding a library to your project as the legacy date-time classes really are a wretched mess. When eventually migrating to Java 8 or later, you need do little more than change your `import` statements.

Comment: +1 because of the Premature Optimization. If I had one advice to give to new programmers, it would be to *first* write their code, make it run as intented, *then* trying to optimize their code and performance, **if** they are even able to see/feel any bottleneck while using their own app. Sometimes it runs too smoothly for our eye alone to grasp, as non-optimized as it can get.